# HDD working on Mac but asks to be formatted on PC

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mac, data-recovery

I have a 1TB Toshiba external HDD, 2 years old. A few days ago it suddenly stopped showing up on my PC. Whenever I connect it, the system asks if I wish to format the HDD and I cannot access my years of stored data.

Surprisingly, if I connect it to my Mac, it shows up and is even accessible. But the Mac is in the office I cannot waste time recovering data. How do I remedy this issue and what's the cause for it? I believe some sectors from my HDD may have failed. Any suggestions for a way to recover my data?

I can format the disk once the data is recovered and see if it still works.

Comment: Your data can't be that important if you 'waste time' on your easiest recovery method.

Comment: I would prefer to work i the office. Not to mention the fact that we have a strict data confidentiality policy. So me connecting my HDD to the officce mac could be counter productive. Plus My mac doesnt have nearly enough space to recover everything.

Comment: Try Paragon NTFS. Paragon NTFS effectively solves the communication problems between the Mac system and NTFS, providing full read and write access to Windows NTFS partitions under OS X.

Comment: @Davidenko You've got it backwards. The drive works for the OP on a Mac, but not on Windows.

Comment: Honestly, step 1 is BACKUP THAT DATA. If this is your only backup and something funny is happening, you need to backup everything while it's still retrievable, and from here out, always keep more than one backup of information, single-points of failure are the biggest cause of data loss in the world. From there, try to run some dskchk or repair tools for the HDD in question. There are plenty of tools to check/fix HDD booting issues.

Comment: I would suggest taking that hard drive and an external hard drive to the office. Copy the data from the dying hard drive to the external hard drive. Once all the data is safely on the external hard drive, discard the dying hard drive, purchase another, then move the data back onto it at home.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the partition is damaged or it just can't be read form Windows for some reason. If MAC is able to mount it properly probably Linux will do as well. You can try booting with some Linux live CD and move the data to a different drive. Once you get all the data copied to another place test the drive using the manufacturer's diagnostics tool. If it's testing in good health you can reformat and use it again.

Comment: If it didn't have enough power to operate then Windows wouldn't be offering to format it.  Windows offers to format it because it doesn't recognize the filesystem as fat or ntfs.